# Handling sessions to web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a requirement where our website can generate a tracking id to pass out to users to track how they come to our website.

The website is an Angular frontend and a .Net Web Api2 backend and they are part of the same domain

My initial plan is to have the the initial tracking url go direct to the api (e.g. http://api.mywebsite.com/t/45mg9) and then this returns a redirect to the relevant page (e.g. http://web.mywebsite.com).

The redirect is working fine but I want to keep track of the initial tracking code as the user might not initially be logged in so need to keep hold of it until they are logged in.

I've tried:

**Cookies**:

On the redirect message I've set a cookie using the following:

```
var response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(tracking.Url);

        var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("tracking", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tracking))
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Path = "/",
            Domain = "mywebsite.com",
            Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddDays(30)
        };
response.Headers.AddCookies(new[] { cookie });
return ResponseMessage(response);
```

And can see the cookie being set on the redirect but then it isn't there when the Web app does subsequent calls to the api.

**Session**

I've enabled sessions in my web api and set the the value but it seems to lose it with redirects.

---

I want to try and keep this within the api as I don't think the web app needs to know about the information being stored, only the api is interested.

How can I go about persisting information (cookie, session etc) being sent to an api? Do I need to tell the web app to pass cookies to the api call?

Answer (score 0):

You can reissue the tracking id from webapp to api in each request by adding a request header with the tracking id.

At web app the tracking id can be persisted in a cookie or localstorage.

For adding the tracking id in header use a httpinterceptor for each call to api.

```
@Injectable()
 export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
constructor() { }
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            TrackingId: localStorage.getItem('trackingId')
        }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
   }
 }
```

Comment: My API does a redirect with the trackingId in the cookie, it isn't passed into the web app through a URI parameter so not sure how to access it? Ideally the cookie issued by the api is always sent per api call